# Use docker to containerize and build an old application

Tags: docker, makefile, build, volume, mount

Our embedded system product is built in an Ubuntu 12.04 with some ancient tools that are no longer available. We have the tools in our local git repo.

Setting up the build environment for a new comer is extremely challenging. I would like to set up the build environment in a docker container, download the source code into a host machine, mount the source code into the container and execute the build so that someone starting fresh doesnt have to endure the challenging setup. Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Here is what I have done so far:

Created a dockerfile to set up the env

```
# Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS is the standard platform for development
FROM ubuntu:12.04.5
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   build-essential \
   dialog \
   autoconf \
   automake \
   libtool \
   libgtk-3-dev \
   default-jdk \
   bison \
   flex \
   php5 \
   php5-pgsql \
   libglib2.0-dev \
   gperf \
   sqlite3 \
   txt2man \
   libssl-dev \
   libudev-dev \
   ia32-libs \
   git

ENV PATH="$PATH:toolchain/bin"
```

The last line (ENV ...) sets the path to the toolchain location. Also there are a few more env variables to set.

On my host machine I run a have my source pulled in to my working dir.

Built the docker image using:

```
docker build --tag=myimage:latest .
```

And then I mounted the source code as a volume to the container using:

```
docker run -it --volume /path/to/host/code:/path/in/container myimage
```

All this works - it mounts the code in the container and I am in the container's terminal, I can see the code. However I dont see the path I set to the toolchain in my dockerfile. I was hoping the path would get set and I could call make.

Is this not how it is supposed to work, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see the path"? If you `echo $PATH` the value doesn't include toolchain/bin? It should, it's even an example of the doc https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#env. However, in your case, I'm not sure it will work as `toolchain/bin` is a relative path so it depends on the current dir in the container.

Comment: This is all see
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin